# Insert Data into Database and display it with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to CodeIgniter

I have the following code in my Model:

```
public function saveVar() {

    $variable_limit=$this->input->post('var');
    $data = array(
        'variable_limit'=>'$variable_limit'
    );

    $this->db->insert('mytable',$data);

}
```

this should fetch Data from html form and insert a row 'variable_limit' into the table 'mytable', the code doent work I see no change in the mysql database.

Assumed that the first code works, I want to display this data to the view, I wrote this Code in my Controller:

```
    function postVar(){

            $this->load->model('tool');
            $this->tool->saveVar();
        }
```

I am trying to transfer the data to the model calling 'tool' by calling the saveVar() which is implemented in my model, does this Code work?

Edit: this is the Code in my View:

```
<form id="myform" action="<?php echo base_url()."tools/file";?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateData();">
```

```
<div> Variable : <input type="number" id="var" name="var" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['var']) ? $_POST['var'] : '' ?>" /></div>
```

Thanks, Elmoud

Comment: Where you are passing the post data to model?

Comment: can you post your form in view page too?

Comment: @Hanan Ashraf  @ Rajkumar thanks for your answers, please see the edit I posted the code for the Form

Comment: @Hanan Ashraf, it did not work, by the way you wrote  $this->load->model in Model and you used the $data array in Model and Rajkumar R used it in Controller, is it relevant ? Please look  at my View Code , I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Hanan Ashraf sorry I meant  Rajkumar  for $this->load->model becuase he wrote it in Model

Comment: @Elmoud you wrote action attribute as well as onsubmit attribute for your form.It won't work together i think.. Submit your form after the success of validation.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:-

Controller:-

```
public function postVar(){
    $variable_limit=$this->input->post('var');
    $data = array(
        'variable_limit'=>$variable_limit
    );
    $this->tool->saveVar($data);
}
```

Model:-

```
public function saveVar($data) {
    $this->load->model('tool');
    $this->db->insert('mytable',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
function postVar(){

            $this->load->model('tool');
            $this->tool->saveVar();
        }
```

**Model**

```
public function saveVar() {

    $variable_limit=$this->input->post('var');
    $data = array(
        'variable_limit'=>$variable_limit
    );

    $this->db->insert('mytable',$data);

}
```

It need not use quotes for variables.Just use  `$variable_limit`as such.

Answer (score 0):

***Controller:***

```
function postVar(){

        $this->load->model('tool');
        $this->tool->saveVar();
    }
```

***Model:***

```
public function saveVar() {
$data = array(
    'variable_limit'=>$this->input->post('var')
);

$this->db->insert('mytable',$data);
```

}